# Mouse no longer working when using a Linksys KVM switch with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mouse, kvm-switch

I have been using a Linksys PS2KVM2 (2 port) switch to toggle between Ubuntu and Windows for years. I recently had a need to add another computer, so I replaced the Linksys 2 port KVM with a Linksys PS2KVM4 (4 port).  I wanted to keep the same brand of switch since the linksys 2 port worked so well.

I should also mention that, with the 2 port switch, I had to use a PS2-to-USB adapter on the mouse line to the Ubuntu computer since my motherboard on that computer only has one PS2 port.

Using this exact same setup, my mouse no longer works on the Ubuntu computer with the 4 port. Both other computers work fine.

I have tried:

- moving the Ubuntu computer to a different port on the KVM
- swapping in different mice

But I'm still not getting the mouse to connect to the Ubuntu computer.

Has anyone experienced this issue with this Linksys product or with Ubuntu in general?  Is there a different setting that may help?

Maybe changing to USB Keyboards and Mice will fix the problem?

Comment: Try booting the computer from a live Ubuntu USB, the try Ubuntu option, and see if the mouse works. If you have Windows, try booting Windows and see if the mouse works. If the mouse does not work, then it is a hardware problem.